# How to draw box plot of the objects from regionprops?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

[image: actual graph]

I would like to plot the mean and percentile as shown in figure.I tried some code to plot box plot but I'm getting something different
[image: output]

```
I = propsSynthesizeImage;
imshow(I)
title('Synthetic Image')
% Create a Binary Image
% Segment the grayscale image by creating a binary image containing    the    objects in the image.
BW = I > 0;
imshow(BW)
title('Binary Image')
s = regionprops(BW, I, {'Centroid','PixelValues','BoundingBox'});
imshow(I);
numObj = numel(s);
title('Standard Deviation of Regions');
hold on
for k = 1 : numObj
    s(k).StandardDeviation = std(double(s(k).PixelValues));
    text(s(k).Centroid(1),s(k).Centroid(2), ...
        sprintf('%2.1f', s(k).StandardDeviation), ...
        'EdgeColor','b','Color','r');
end
figure
boxplot(1:numObj,[s.StandardDeviation])
xlabel('Region Label Number');
ylabel('Standard Deviation');
hold off
```

Answer (score 1):

The boxplot visualizes a distribution. Currently, you're plotting scalars.

To plot the distribution (and have Matlab find median, quantiles, etc), plot

```
boxplot(1:numObj,{s.PixelValues})
```

Note that boxplot will not show standard deviations (instead, it shows the inter-quartile range), and that it may give misleading results if the underlying pixel values have a multi-modal distribution.

Comment: how to plot mean median and extreme values as in the figure?max and min of the 10% central value of the object